# keras ValueError in classification shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification

Here is my code:

```
# data consists of 1 dimensional data (3277 elements). Number of data is 439  
train_data = .... # numpy.ndarray
# I would like to classify data into 5 classes.
train_labels = .... # numpy.ndarray

print(train_data.shape) # -> Shape of train_data: (439, 3277)
print('Shape of train_labels:', train_labels.shape) # -> Shape of train_labels: (439,)
# prepare 5 one hot encoding array
categorical_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, 5)
print('Shape of categorical_labels:', categorical_labels.shape) # -> Shape of categorical_labels: (439, 5)

# I make a model to have 3277-elements data and classify data into 5 labels.
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu', input_shape=(3277,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
])
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, categorical_labels, epochs=5, verbose=1) # A
#model.fit(data, train_labels, epochs=5, verbose=1) # B
```

When I try with the line marked 'A', I get this error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (5,)
```

With 'B', it runs properly(without apparent errors and the machine returns high score)

Apparently, the error concerns difference in the shapes... when I want to use `keras.utils.to_categorical`, how can I modify my code?

Another question is why this case works (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py) while my case not..

Structures look similar... to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` does not expect labels in the one-hot encoding format, you should use `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`.

In short, with respect to your case:

- `train_labels` => `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`
- `categorical_labels` => `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`